# Issue getting image width after dynamic load. Why?

Tags: jquery, dynamic, load, width

I am loading images into a div, and then initiating a carousel to the the newly loaded images.  Everything is working correctly, except I can't get the script to get the image's widths and set it.

This is what I currently have...

Get image size function

```
function imgSize() {
    $('img').each(function() {
        var imgWidth = $(this).width();
        var imgHeight = $(this).height();
        $(this).attr('height', imgHeight);
        $(this).attr('width', imgWidth);
    });
}
```

Load new page, call image size function, and carousel function

```
$('.menu a').live('click', function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var page = id + '.html'
        $('#portfolio').load( page , function() {
            imgSize();
            $('#portfolio').carouFredSel(settings);
            $('#bodyFooter span').show();
        });
    });
```

You can see an example here: http://www.amandarecker.com/siteTest  When you click on Beauty, all the images stack up on each other, or don't even show up.  When I am viewing the source with firebug, the width is set to 0.  Why?

Hopefully someone can help... Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i may be wrong but you are probably trying to get the images width too fast. ie the image hasnt loaded yet so its width is returning 0.

try adding load to your function.

```
function imgSize(){
    $("img").load(function(){
        var width = $(this).width();
        var height = $(this).height();
        $(this).attr("width",width).attr("height",height);
    });
}
```

this will only attempt to get the values once the images have fully loaded.

Comment: I think it would be better to just put the whole thing into `$(document).load(function(){});` or add the width and height attributes to your img tags

Comment: It looks to me like the imgSize function is being called after an ajax request "$('#portfolio').load( page , function() {" etc. so if it was put in $(document).load... it wouldnt fire on the images loaded in via ajax. Also its worth noting images dont have to be fully loaded for $(document).load to fire.

Answer (score 2):

you might need to access the DOM of the image, try:

```
function imgSize() {
    $('img').each(function() {
        var imgWidth = $(this)[0].naturalWidth;
        var imgHeight = $(this)[0].naturalHeight;
        $(this).attr('height', imgHeight);
        $(this).attr('width', imgWidth);
    });
}
```

I'm not sure how you are loading your images but here is an example:

```
function loadImage(src, f)
{ 
  var img = new Image();

  $(img).load(function() {
    $(this).hide();
     if(f) f(img);
  }).error(function() {
    return false;
  }).attr('src', src);
}

loadImage('path/to/image.png', function(image) {
  // access image.naturalWidth and image.naturalHeight here to get the dimensions
});
```

So if you load in some new html (it should probably be inserted on the page first), try:

```
// passive (wait for load)
$(html).find('img').load(function() {
  var imgWidth = $(this).width();
  var imgHeight = $(this).height();
  //var imgWidth = $(this)[0].naturalWidth;
  //var imgHeight = $(this)[0].naturalHeight;
  $(this).attr('height', imgHeight);
  $(this).attr('width', imgWidth);
});

// aggressive (load them yourself)
$(html).find('img').each(function() {
  $this = $(this);
  loadImage($(this).attr('src'), function(image) {
    $this.attr('width', image.naturalWidth).attr('height', image.naturalHeight);
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you give me a bit more info?  I am still new to jQUery so I am unsure where to place this...

Comment: Thanks for the update - But this doesn't work.  After checking Firebug, now the hight and width comes back 0.

Comment: ah i think i misunderstood the question - i thought you were dynamically loading the image. For images already on the page check @Ed Fryed answer - and no prob, sorry for misunderstanding the question

Comment: I am dynamically loading the images...  When I am loading in a new .html file, it contains a list of images that are loaded.  These newly loaded images need to width set to them.  I can't add them on my own since there are over 50 images.

Comment: First off, thanks for the continuous help.  I am a bit confused as to where I would place this code to test.  I am still new at jQuery.  Am I using your 3rd edit in place of the imgSize function?

Comment: No problem. Firstly how are you loading the html and how and where are you putting it on the page?

Comment: I have a link with an ID of beauty.  When clicked, it loads an html page called beauty.html into ul#portfolio.  beauty.html contains <li>'s of images.  It's replacing the current <li> in portfolio on the index.html page.  After beauty.html is loaded, the carousel and it's settings are called at the same time imgSize function is called.

Answer (score 0):

First Off, The js answers are great, you may also try updating your IMG tagby putting in width="xxx" height="xxx" for image.. The Dom doesn't care about img height and can expand around it, the js doesn't understand the height of an image not loaded - needs to know size before script and you can just hardcode it first and then overwrite.

Another method is to load the images in a hidden div, or lazyload, and then run your script on completion of that execution.   good luck!